# How to restore font via \usefont command? (or in other ways)

Tags: fonts, lyx, font-encodings, hebrew

I'm triyng to use [webomints package](https://ctan.org/pkg/webomints?lang=en) with Hebrew

Here is the simple file:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Yehuda CLM}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}.}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand{\showb}[1]{\wb{20}{24}#1}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
יחלילחך

\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}\char97 

אבגדה
\end{document}
```

If I removing the last Hebrew line, it's works...
But, if not, this what I get:
[image]

I assuming that it's because the `\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}` command, how can I fix it (restore it)?

Thank you!!

Comment: Use braces to keep the effect of the command local: `{\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}\char97 }`

Comment: Alternatively, you can put `\normalfont` after the font change to return to the normal font (but @UlrikeFischer 's solution is easier, of course).